# Termcap "cl" command doesn't clear screen

Tags: c, terminal, termcap

I can't seem to get `termcap`'s "cl" command to work, but the terminal escape code does.

For example:

```
#include <termcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    tputs(tgetstr("cl", NULL), 1, putchar);
}
```

This doesn't change the terminal. But when I run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\e[2J");
}
```

or if I call `` echo `tput cl` ``
The terminal is cleared.

Why does this happen? Shouldn't `termcap` give that same escape code?

EDIT: Fixed writing characters

EDIT2: It's because i didn't call `tgetent()` before calling `tgetstr()`. Thanks guys!

Comment: The tgetstr() function returns NULL if the capability was not found. Question now is - why can't it find it...

Comment: According to the GNU manual for termcap, the `cl` capability is available on all systems. Hmm...

Comment: Your `ft_puts` function is super broken, and you didn't call `setupterm`. This can't work.

Comment: ... actually, let me amend that. Your `ft_puts` might work on little-endian platforms.

Comment: To expand on melpomene's point, your function takes an `int` which is at least two bytes and writes one byte of it. What is in that byte? Who knows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before interrogating with `tgetstr()`, you need to find the description of the user's terminal with `tgetent()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   // getenv
#include <termcap.h>  // tgetent tgetstr

int main(void)
{
    char buf[1024];
    char *str;

    tgetent(buf, getenv("TERM"));
    str = tgetstr("cl", NULL);
    fputs(str, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `-ltermcap`

Comment: ...or simply `-ltermcap`.